# Настройка меню в админке

Tags: битрикс

На сайте в футере имеются ссылки навигации на страницы сайта.
Нужно поменять некоторые ссылки, но не могу найти, где это настраивается из админки.
Вот код самого блока

```
<?if (!defined("B_PROLOG_INCLUDED") || B_PROLOG_INCLUDED!==true)die();?>

<?
if (!empty($arResult)){

    $menuLength = count($arResult);

    if (($menuLength % 2) == 0) {
        $menuMiddle = ($menuLength / 2);
    }else{
        $menuMiddle = (($menuLength -  1) / 2)+1;
    }

    ?><div class="nav inline">
        <ul><?
    for ($i = 0; $i < $menuMiddle ; $i++) {
        ?><li>
            <a href="<?=$arResult[$i]["LINK"]?>"
               title="<?=$arResult[$i]["TEXT"]?>">
               <?=$arResult[$i]["TEXT"]?>
            </a>
          </li><?
    }
    ?>  </ul>
    </div><?

    ?><nav class="inline">
        <ul class="nav_foot inline"><?
    for ($i = $menuMiddle; $i < $menuLength ; $i++) {
        ?><li>
            <a href="<?=$arResult[$i]["LINK"]?>"
               title="<?=$arResult[$i]["TEXT"]?>">
               <?=$arResult[$i]["TEXT"]?>
            </a>
          </li><?
    }
    ?>  </ul>
    </nav><?
}
?>
```

т.е. нужно настроить блок с классом `nav_foot inline`.
Вот путь этого файла:

```
/local/templates/main/components/bitrix/menu/bottom_menu/template.php
```

Где можно найти настройку данного блока в админке?

PS.
добавил ещё блок, который нужно настроить из админки

```
<? if (!defined("B_PROLOG_INCLUDED") || B_PROLOG_INCLUDED !== true) die(); ?>
<? if (!empty($arResult)){ ?>
    <nav class="inline">
        <!--1 LEVEL-->
        <ul class="nav_head inline dropdown">
            <?php
            $previousLevel = 0;
            foreach ($arResult as $arItem){ ?>
            <? if ($previousLevel && $arItem["DEPTH_LEVEL"] < $previousLevel){
                echo str_repeat("</ul></li>", ($previousLevel - $arItem["DEPTH_LEVEL"]));
            } ?>

            <? if ($arItem["IS_PARENT"]){ ?>
            <? if ($arItem["DEPTH_LEVEL"] == 1){ ?>
            <li class='dropdown-top'>
                <a href="<?= $arItem["LINK"] ?>"class="dropdown-top <? if ($arItem["SELECTED"]): ?>dropdown-top<? else: ?>dropdown-top<? endif ?>"><?= $arItem["TEXT"] ?>
                </a>

                <!--<li><a href="#" title="О компании">О компании</a></li>-->
                <!--<li class="dropdown-top"><a class="dropdown-top" href="all-services.html">Услуги</a>-->


                <!-- 2 LEVEL-->
                <ul class="dropdown-inside">
                    <? }else{ ?>
                    <li <? if ($arItem["SELECTED"]): ?> class="new"<? else:?>class="new"<? endif; ?>><a href="<?= $arItem["LINK"] ?>"><?= $arItem["TEXT"] ?></a>
                        <!--3 LEVEL-->
                        <ul class="two">
                            <? } ?>

                            <? }else{ ?>
                                <? if ($arItem["PERMISSION"] > "D"){ ?>
                                    <? if ($arItem["DEPTH_LEVEL"] == 1){ ?>
                                        <li class="level new">
                                            <a href="<?= $arItem["LINK"] ?>"class="<? if ($arItem["SELECTED"]): ?>root-item-selected<? else: ?>root-item<? endif ?>"><?= $arItem["TEXT"] ?></a>
                                        </li>
                                    <? }else{ ?>
                                        <li class="level new"
                                            <? if ($arItem["SELECTED"]): ?> class="item-selected"<? endif ?>>
                                            <a href="<?= $arItem["LINK"] ?>"><?= $arItem["TEXT"] ?></a>
                                        </li>
                                    <? } ?>

                                <? }else{ ?>

                                    <? if ($arItem["DEPTH_LEVEL"] == 1){ ?>
                                        <li>
                                            <a href="" class="<? if ($arItem["SELECTED"]): ?>root-item-selected<? else: ?>root-item<? endif ?>"title="<?= GetMessage("MENU_ITEM_ACCESS_DENIED") ?>"><?= $arItem["TEXT"] ?>
                                            </a>
                                        </li>
                                    <? }else{ ?>
                                        <li>
                                            <a href="" class="denied" title="<?= GetMessage("MENU_ITEM_ACCESS_DENIED") ?>"><?= $arItem["TEXT"] ?>
                                            </a>
                                        </li>
                                    <? } ?>
                                <? } ?>
                                <? $previousLevel = $arItem["DEPTH_LEVEL"]; ?>
                                <!--</ul>-->
                                <!-- END 3 LEVEL-->

                                <!--</li>-->

                                <!--</ul>-->
                                <!-- END 2 LEVEL-->


                                <!--</li>-->
                            <? } ?>
                            <? } ?>
                            <? if ($previousLevel > 1){//close last item tags?>
                                <?= str_repeat("</ul></li>", ($previousLevel - 1)); ?>
                            <? } ?>

                            <? if ($previousLevel > 1){//close last item tags?>
                                <?= str_repeat("</ul></li>", ($previousLevel - 1)); ?>
                            <? } ?>
                        </ul>
                        <!-- END 1 LEVEL-->
    </nav>
<? } ?>
```

т.е. `dropdown-inside` это вложенные пункты меню. Где их можно поменять в админке?

Comment: Включаете эрмитаж (http://joxi.ru/823vgE4c655kMm), потом наводите мышку на меню и вуаля http://joxi.ru/GrqGVxKIN66jB2

Comment: @Oleksandr, благодарю, один блок настроил. Но есть блок с выпадающим меню. Как добраться до этих вложенных пунктов меню? По предложенному вами способу можно настроить только пункты верхнего уровня

Comment: https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/learning/course/index.php?COURSE_ID=43&LESSON_ID=3254
посмотрите тут. Файл должен быть в папке, которая отвечает за вывод раздела. В админке по файловой структуре гляньте.

Comment: @Oleksandr, по предложенной вами ссылке находится только описание  структуры файлов. А мне нужно настроить вложенные пункты меню из админки.  Подскажите пожалуйста, как ещё можно найти данные настройки? выше добавил код данного блока, подскажите пожалуйста

Comment: http://c2n.me/3P1mMjV здесь нужно искать?

Comment: это реальный проэкт, или нет?
И если знаете, ка кн со создать чат, давайте перейдем туда, дабы тут не плодить флуд

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67880/discussion-between-oleksandr-and-word).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Структура битрикса предполагает, что меню будет находиться в файловой структуре вида `.{название меню}.menu.php`. Меню является иерархически наследуемым. Файлы меню размещаются в папках тех разделов сайта, где требуется показ соответствующих типов меню. Если для данного раздела не создан соответствующий файл меню, система производит поиск файла в каталоге уровнем выше.
То-есть в вашем случае, дабы редактировать меню в футере, нужно в структуре найти файл `.bottom.menu.php`, и редактировать его, а чтобы удалить выпадающий пункт "Карта сайта" из раздела `/services/`, нужно редактировать файл `/services/.left.menu.php`.